Animated film with a kingdom of winged people
Someone help me figure out the name of this movie please; I'm going insane.
In the beginning of it, it's this race of winged people living in a kingdom. Half the world is colourful and the other half is black and evil-looking. Now, the king, queen and their baby are sleeping, when the king's jealous sister sneaks in and plots to poison them in their sleep with some kinda orb of magic. The queen is killed, but the baby wakes up, and so does the king, and the evil sister is caught. She gets her wings cut off and is then exiled. The main character of the movie, years later, helps her by accident. 
That's all I remember. It's animated and named after the main character. It's a one-word title.  It's in English and it came out after 2000, before 2010
Please help.

What style of animation? CG, hand-drawn, stop-motion/claymation, anime-style, Disney-style? You saw it in English but was it likely to have been dubbed from some other language?

You're looking for the animated film Delgo from 2008. In the beginning:

After having left their own world due to a loss of natural resources, the winged humanoid Nohrin settle on Jhamora with the permission of the ground-dwelling Lokni. But some of the Nohrin, led by would-be conqueror Sedessa, believe in the superiority of their own race and try to take land away from the Lokni. The parents of Delgo, a Lokni, are killed in the resulting conflict. Nohrin King Zahn is horrified by the war and admonishes Sedessa, who then poisons the Queen and almost kills Zahn as well. She is subsequently banished, and her wings are clipped off. 

Here's the trailer:




Bless your soul. Thank you
